# How to fix "Unfortunately, the process xxx has stopped"?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, root-access, samsung

I was having some trouble with my rooted Samsung GS3, so I "tried" to perform a reset by flashing a stock ROM in ODIN. Once I booted it back up, the first thing I saw was "Unfortunantly, the process android.process.media has stopped." I thought that was weird but continued with the setup process, but it kept happening frequently. Media, gapps, Play Store, gallery, contacts and others were "unfortunately stopping". I can't open the play store, camera, phone app, contacts and some others. Now, I use only the messaging, Internet, and Youtube apps. I can't download any apps, or anything really. I've tried to reflash the ROM with ODIN, but that does nothing. I've flashed CWM to it but that doesn't even working properly. I tried to restore a backup I have on my External SD but when I hit restore in CWM it just says "Couldn't open directory. No files found." Device is SGH-I747. I'm going insane with this. Please help, any response is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the data and cache of every app that gives you this error.

It's very common that this junk causes troubles because they were set up in other conditions of the Android SO.